# FB sending app invites, plist facebook link not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

I am trying to use the FBSDKShareKit to send app invites. I am using this standard code to load the friends picker:

```
    FBSDKAppInviteContent *content =[[FBSDKAppInviteContent alloc] init];
    content.appLinkURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://fb.me/97938247932749274"];


    // present the dialog. Assumes self implements protocol `FBSDKAppInviteDialogDelegate`
    [FBSDKAppInviteDialog showWithContent:content
                                 delegate:self];
```

Problem is when I try to run it I get a crash with the error: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'InvalidOperationException', reason: 'fb97938247932749274 is not registered as a URL scheme. Please add it in your Info.plist'. This is my plist setup:

[image]

Checked some other threads on this, most people seemed to run into issues because they got the case wrong on URL Schemes or URL types. I have messed around and tried various combinations. The one I have should be correct, but it's not working. Could anyone give me some pointers on what might be going wrong here please?

EDIT: I also have FacebookAppID and FacebookDisplayName in my plist and the appID is the same as the one below without the fb prefix.

Comment: You need to have fb{your_app_id} registered as an URL scheme in your plist (remember to just use the alphanumerics, and don't include the "://" part).

Comment: Sorry forgot to say I have done that too

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem. Edited the plist file over and over again in xcode. After some tries I looked in the info.plist file with my text editor and the URL Schemes string "fbxxxxxxx" was not correct (the entry pointed to another app but I am sure that this was not what I typed in xcode!).

Corrected the Schemes entry restarted xcode and worked like a charm.